# Content in array of ajax call disappearing after end of function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Sorry if I'm being dumb, I'm new to using Jquery with Ajax calls. After looking for hours I couldn't find a clear solution to my problem. I have a function that starts when a button gets clicked. In this function a make an Ajax call to a .json file on the same folder. The content returns as a string, which it's not clear to me why since it's a .json file, but I parse it with the $.parseJSON() method. When I get the data after parsing, I tried storing on an array by using the .push() method. Later I try to append all of the content to my html file, which my code does, but at the end of the function the content of my array goes away, as well as the content loaded in my html which only gets display for like half of a second on my browser.

I'm really stuck with this part any help will be appreciated! :)

Here it's my method for when the button gets clicked, along with my array where I'm trying to store the result of the call:

```
    var results = [];
var resultDiv = $('#results')

$('#go').click(function(){
    $.ajax({url : "cat.json" , async:false}).done(function(data){
        // save results
        saveResults($.parseJSON(data));
        displayResults(results);
        console.log('I got something!');

    })


        console.log('sorted!');
})
```

Here it's my save function:

```
function saveResults(content){

    content.forEach(function(data){
        results.push(data);
    })
}
```

My guess is that I'm not making the Ajax call the right way

Comment: @JerdineSabio read https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/#jqXHR

Comment: Oh I see, will delete comment

Comment: @Daniel.. read the api docs to see $.parseJSON is deprecated.. also you could have checked the ajax response and used console.log for something useful like logging the parsed data

Comment: @yezzz  I tried without the .parseJSON but for some reason the content is being returned as a string, when I thought it would be returned as an object since it's a .json file. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is updated solution:

1. Be sure your json source is valid, in case of doubt you can use a dummy link such as `http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json`.
2. Do not put `<button>` into for, it will trigger an post and will refresh your page
3. Use `$.each(content, function(k, v)` in order to retrive not only the key

Last thing, there is a snippet tool that allow you to split your HTML, CSS and JavaScript code into this discussion, such as I did. I encourage you to use it. It will easy the communication!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var results = [];
    var resultDiv = $('#results')
    $('#go').click(function() {
        $.ajax({url : "http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json" , async:false}).done(function(data){
            // save results
            saveResults($.parseJSON(data));
            displayResults(results);
            console.log('I got something!');
        });
        function saveResults(content) {
            $.each(content, function(k, v) {
                results.push(v);
                console.log(k, v);
            })
        }
    });

    function displayResults(input) {
        input.forEach(function(data, index) {
            resultDiv.append('<div class="panel">' +
                '<div class="panel-body">' +
                ' <h3><a href="' + data['url'] + '">Blah, I say</a></h3>' +
                '<div class="url">' + data['url'] + '</div>' +
                '<div>Relevance: 0.54</div>' +
                ' <div class="excerpt">' +
                'Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty.' +
                'Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. ' +
                'Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. ' +
                'Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty...' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                ' </div> ');
        });
    }

    function sortResults(input) {
        input.sort(function(item1, item2) {
            return item2.relevance - item1.relevance;
        });
    }
})
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="search.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="heading">Search!</h1>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="terms" id="search" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-primary" id ='go' >Go</button></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div id="results">
        <div class="panel">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <h3><a href="http://blah.blah.blah">Blah, I say</a></h3>
            <div class="url">http://blah.blah.blah</div>
            <div>Relevance: 0.54</div>
            <div class="excerpt">
              Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty. Excerpty...
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="search.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: still same issue, when I use $.each() :(

Comment: I just noticed that, for some reason my browser gets refreshed when it exits the function

Comment: I adjusted it, try it like this. It run fine from the snippet. You have to wait 15 secondes in order to get the content but it works ^^!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/omardanniel/063rqwnh/2/#&togetherjs=CjysFDMRIu here it's a link with a full copy of my code, since I don't really know any other way to share it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/omardanniel/063rqwnh/10/#&togetherjs=CjysFDMRIu Sorry about that here it's the code with javascript

Comment: Remove the `<form>` tag and its closing `</form>`. Sorry my wife called me... So np for the first link I didn't even took a look :P

Comment: thanks! that solves the issue where it was disappearing, but is there a reason why the content of the array still disappears?

Comment: Because you're using only the key of they `$.each`. Use `function(k, v)` instead and use look with that updated example please.

Comment: NVM! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: My pleasure my friend! Sorry, I has been slow on that one, I was doing few things in same time.